# Good practice of showing Items details in the same table's page

Tags: interface-design, applications

I have an application which have table of Item, now I'm wondering what is the best practice of showing Items details :

**Option 1**

- Search an Item, then click on details button of that Item to open a new page which show all details

**Option 2**

- Option 1 +
- A quick show In the same page, which show only the important details.

---

My question is :

- Is it a good idea to use the second option?
- If yes, In which side I should to display this details?

Comment: *Really* depends on how *much* additional data there is to show. Same page is best, but not always feasible.

Comment: Maybe this question would be better fit for [UX](https://ux.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Joonas should we vote to migrate it, Or I should to delete it and create a new one there?

Comment: You know, I've never really understood that in this specific Stack Exchange site. Because `voting to close and migrate` only has one option and that is this sites `meta` side. So the way I see it, you either have to flag down a moderator to migrate it to a specific site or just delete the question yourself and move it to the other site manually.

Comment: Thank you @Scott, my table have 5 details, but in total there are more then 20 detail of each row, 10 are more important, so is it a good practice to show them with the table?

Comment: ...and I was just kind of thinking out loud. **I can't decide if this belongs on that site or in this one.** To get the best result, you kinda have to take both user experience and graphic design into consideration. Though I think this question would benefit from some extra info. Like the platform... If it's like a desktop app, you may have different ways to solve the problem than like let's say... a mobile website or a mobile app. I think... if possible, you should provide some sort of basic mockup / example of the data you have and how it would sit in each of these options.

Comment: @Joonas the theory behind the close reason for migration is to let the moderators determine if and where it should be migrated to. So that option just brings it to moderator attention. The reality is, many questions fit multiple stacks and often if something isn't wildly off topic, it's fine. I think this falls into that. It is a design question. But there may also be users as UX with helpful information -- since cross-posting isn't great.. I think it's up to the user to determine where it may fit best.

Comment: YCF_L, it again really is dependent upon the details themselves. If they are something like 20 numbers... you could do a simple table with show/hide jquery.. if it's 20 different paragraphs of information then a page or full page modal window may be more feasible. The determining fact would be how cumbersome seeing all the extra info is to the user. If it really requires time to ingest all the extra info, then you may want t displayed on its own. If it's brief, quick info, then same page may work.

Comment: @Scott It is just some simple information about patient, first name, last name, birth day, address, ...,  beside I'm using desktop app (JavaFX), I think I will go with the second option, thank you Scott I appreciate it

Comment: I would probably be inclined to do the same page as well for that type of information. It's data the user may want to record or see briefly but won't "mull over" to any great degree..

Comment: @scott, that much is obvious. What I don't get is why? Other stack exchange sites have multiple migration options, although they are limited in any of them as far as I know. Why can't we have a limited pool of sites to migrate to as well? The reason why they are limited in any site is probably that people don't accidentally migrate to a completely unrelated site ( though that is just my guess). In this site migrating to "meta" isn't the only one we need. Photo, UX, Super User and  Stack overflowwould be nice...

Comment: I do not disagree @Joonas :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same page or different page is *really* dependent upon the details themselves.

- If the `details` are something like 20 numbers... you could do a simple table with show/hide jquery on the same page.
- If the `details` are 20 different paragraphs of information then a page  may be more feasible.

The determining factor would be how cumbersome seeing all the extra data is to the user.

If ingesting the extra data requires time and a user may need to refer to it multiple times to "get" it all, then you may want to displayed on its own.

If the nature of the `details` are brief, quick info, such as  contact information, then the same page may work best. Primarily because the `details` would be something a user may need to quickly refer to then dismiss. If there's no cause to spend a great deal of time looking at the extra information, then an easy way to see it, then hide it is often more user-friendly.